# Object name reference not going out of scope

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, c#-6.0

I've spotted a very confusing behavior:

I have two `for` blocks. I declare two distinct objects with the same name `newDevice` inside each one. I expect that the first object goes out of scope when the first `for` block ends, and a for a new object to be created in the second `for` block.

What actually happens is that the initial value is never "released" from the variable name. The variable name still references the first object.

The compiler doesn't complain about already declared object, and if I don't use the `var` keyword in the second attribution, a "cannot resolve symbol" error arises.

Here's the simplified code:

```
/* First "for" loop */
var masters = networkDiscoveryCompletedEventArgs.ConnectionInfos.Where(x => x.DataModelHandshake.DeviceId == masterId).ToList();
foreach (var connectionInfoMaster in masters)
{
    // First declaration. newDevice's type, after construction, is "MasterDevice".
    var newDevice = new MasterDevice
    {
        DeviceName = connectionInfoMaster.DataModelHandshake.Name,
        DeviceId = connectionInfoMaster.DataModelHandshake.DeviceId,
        ConnectionInfo = connectionInfoMaster
    };

    MasterDevices.Add(newDevice);
}

/* Second "for" loop */
var slaves = networkDiscoveryCompletedEventArgs.ConnectionInfos.Where(x => x.DataModelHandshake.DeviceId != masterId).ToList();
foreach (var connectionInfoSlave in slaves)
{  
    // Second declaration. Inspecting newDevice in debbug mode,
    // it's not undeclared at this point. Instead, it retains
    // the previous object reference ("MasterDevice"). newDevice's type, after construction,
    // is also "MasterDevice".
    var newDevice = new SlaveDevice
    {
        DeviceName = connectionInfoSlave.DataModelHandshake.Name,
        DeviceId = connectionInfoSlave.DataModelHandshake.DeviceId,
        ConnectionInfo = connectionInfoSlave
    };

    SlaveDevices.Add(newDevice);
}
```

Using different names solves the issue.

Am I missing something, or is it a compiler bug?

This never happened before, and I'm really confused.

Comment: Could this be just am issue with the debugger? For example, what happens when you do `Console.WriteLine(newDevice.GetType());`?

Comment: Could be a bug. What happens if you explicitly declare type instead of using `var`?

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov Declaring the type explicitly has no effect.

Comment: @svick The behavior is now even stranger. After adding `MessageBox.Show("newDevice Type = " + newDevice.GetType());`, the result on the dialog box is correct (MasterDevice then SlaveDevice), but the debugger (Intellisense and Imediate Window alike) says the type is wrong. It suggests it's a debugger bug, but I only used the debugger in the first place because conditional statements where failing. But now even the conditionals are working, even though the  debugger is still wrong. I removed the `MessageBox` and nothing changed.

Comment: The runtime might be using the same memory position for the variable which points to somewhere on the heap that the GC hasn't yet collected. And since you can't write code to access the "old" variable, it's OK.

Comment: By the way, is this a release or debug compilation?

Comment: @PauloMorgado this is a debug compilation. The original problem was that the code was not doing what it was supposed to. Instead of creating a new `SlaveDevice`, it was using the previous `MasterDevice` instance, with all its values (not the new ones used in the constructor). Btw, `SlaveDevice` and `MasterDevice` inherit from `BaseDevice`. The whole problem is that I could only access the "old" variable content.

Comment: @RafaelMoura, can you build a simple program that reproduces this?